# Scroll Event is too choppy in IE11 and Chrome is suggesting to improve RAIL performance in my React App

Tags: javascript, html, performance, reactjs, internet-explorer-11

I am facing an issue of performance bottleneck where I am not able to improve the animation applied to my table columns on scroll.

The problem statement is to freeze first three column of my grid table. To achieve that I have done this

```
componentDidMount(previousProps, previousState){
        this.setState({showFilterOptions: showFilter})
        $table = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.gridTable)
        $tbody_table = $table.querySelector('tbody') || ''
        $tbody_table.scrollLeft = this.state.scrollLeft
        $tableContainer = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.gridContainer)
        $table = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.gridTable)
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {        
        var d = document
        var errorElement = d.querySelector('.error')
        if( errorElement !== null && errorElement.classList[0] === 'ddl_select_menu') {
            var elem = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(errorElement)
            elem.scrollIntoView(true)
        }
        console.log('DidUpdate Called!! for placeHolder Changes!')
        $thead_table = $table.querySelector('thead') || ''
        $tbody_table = $table.querySelector('tbody') || ''
        $th_thead_table = $table.querySelectorAll('thead th') || ''
        $tbody_table_first = $table.getElementsByClassName('col1') || ''
        $tbody_table_second = $table.getElementsByClassName('col2') || ''
        $tbody_table_third = $table.getElementsByClassName('col3') || ''
    }


applyScrollChanges(){
        scrollLeft =  $tbody_table.scrollLeft
        $thead_table.style.cssText += ";left:"+ -scrollLeft + 'px'
        var str = scrollLeft + 'px'
        for (var i = 0; i < $th_thead_table.length; i++){
            $th_thead_table[i].style.cssText += "; left: " + str 
        }

        str =  $tbody_table.scrollLeft + 'px'

        for(var i = 0; i < $tbody_table_first.length; i++ ) {
            $tbody_table_first[i].style.cssText += "; left: " + str 
            $tbody_table_second[i].style.cssText += "; left: " + str 
            $tbody_table_third[i].style.cssText += "; left: " + str
        }
    }


    handleScrollEvent(e){
        if (!ticking) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
                self.applyScrollChanges();
                ticking = false;
            });
        }
        ticking = true;
    }
```

Inside my render I have this

```
<div className='constrainer' onScroll={this.handleScrollEvent} id="gridContainer" ref="gridContainer">
<table className='table' id="gridTable" key="gridTable" ref="gridTable">
  --- Code for table header --
  --- code to table body ----
```

In table body i have given first three columns three classes col1, col2, col3.

Now When I am running this on IE11 I am experiencing a choppy and slow performance. and Paint time its taking is as high at 45msec.

Please suggest me How to improve this. What Comes in my mind is that I can get only visible table element in that are currently in view and apply those style changes only in those tds.

The height of the table is **597px.**

Comment: Hello, just a matter of making things easier - could you provide jsfiddle with mockup table data?

Comment: Use debounce to avoid unnecessary multiple calls.

Comment: @AdamK. I will. Need sometime to make that

Answer (score 1):

Although it doesn't answer your question directly, the way, as you hinted at in your closing comments, is displaying only "chunks" of data at any one time.

This can be done in a variety of ways, but is deceptively involved.

Luckily an excellent, robust solution already exists in a library called react-virtualized: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized

In particular, their table example seems particularlly relevant: 
https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/Table

Answer (score 0):

First you should always apply some throttle to scroll events. And interval could be slightly higher for IE.
Secondly, you should never update DOM inside a for loop. This has a huge performance impact.